# Stripe - PHP Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Charge' not found

Tags: php, class

I've been following the Stripe documentation and I am unable to create a "charge".

Charge.php

```
require('/var/www/stripe-php-2.1.1/lib/Stripe.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("KEY_HERE");

\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 400,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source" => "TOKEN_HERE", // obtained with Stripe.js
  "description" => "Charge for test@example.com"
));
?>
```

I'm able to process the first command "\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("KEY_HERE");" but receive an error when processing the next and receive the following error: 
"Class 'Stripe\Charge' not found in /var/www/charge.php"

Comment: post your code into Stripe.php

Comment: Maybe try using composer to install Stripe or get it again from GitHub. It has loaded \Stripe but not \Charge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't use [composer to install the Stripe library](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries#php-library) you will need to manually include all of the Stripe classes.

Composer is the preferred way as it will handle the autoloading of classes. Here is a sample composer file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "stripe/stripe-php": "2.*"
  }
}
```

And then from a command line you would need to run `composer update` while in the directory for your project. Afterwards, just add `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of your php file.

Otherwise, replace `require('/var/www/stripe-php-2.1.1/lib/Stripe.php');`with this code to include all of the classes:

```
$stripeClassesDir = __DIR__ . '/stripe-php-2.1.1/lib/';
$stripeUtilDir    = $stripeClassesDir . 'Util/';
$stripeErrorDir   = $stripeClassesDir . 'Error/';

set_include_path($stripeClassesDir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $stripeUtilDir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $stripeErrorDir);

function __autoload($class)
{
    $parts = explode('\\', $class);
    require end($parts) . '.php';
}
```

Comment: You would also need to include this folder: $stripeHttpClientDir   = $stripeClassesDir . 'HttpClient/';

Answer (score 25):

Here is an updated answer to this question.

From Dana at Stripe:

> If you prefer not to use Composer, our latest PHP bindings (>=2.x)
>   include a init.php file that you can add to your project. Download and
>   unzip the folder whereever you'd like, then include this init.php at
>   the top of your scripts you use to communicate with the Stripe API,
>   changing the path to the location of this file. Just like this:
>   require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php')

And that's what worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me much better than the selected answer. This should be the selected answer here.

Comment: A clean way to include Stripe, without other dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. This answer ended days of trying to figure this out without using composer (which I find confounding).

Comment: This generally works but the init.php file I got with Stripe doesn't include a few files: DefaultLogger.php and LoggerInterface.php. LoggerInterface needs to come first.