# Call to undefined method Stripe\Subscription::retrieve()

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe within CodeIgniter and here is how I have it set up:

Within my Stripe controller, I am calling the library by the following:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/init.php');
```

This is per [Stripe - PHP Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Charge' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846062/stripe-php-fatal-error-class-stripe-charge-not-found)

The function that is failing is:

```
function cancelSubscription($stripeaccount){

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($stripeaccount);
    $sub_id = $customer->subscriptions->data[0]->id;    
    echo $sub_id;
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($sub_id);
    $subscription->cancel();

}
```

I've confirmed through the echo that the \Stripe\Customer call on the first line is in fact working and pulling back the subscription ID. However, it's failing when I try to retrieve the subscription on the 4th line with:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe\Subscription::retrieve()
```

Stripe's documentation gives the following example:

```
$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve("sub_8PVEGdSaepQU26");
$sub->cancel();
```

And as you can see, with exception to my variable names, it's the same. I'm coming up blank on this one, any help would be appreciated.

Results of:

> print_r(get_class_methods('\Stripe\Subscription'));

```
[0] => instanceUrl [1] => cancel [2] => save [3] => deleteDiscount [4] => baseUrl [5] => refresh [6] => className [7] => classUrl [8] => init [9] => __construct [10] => __set [11] => __isset [12] => __unset [13] => __get [14] => offsetSet [15] => offsetExists [16] => offsetUnset [17] => offsetGet [18] => keys [19] => constructFrom [20] => refreshFrom [21] => serializeParameters [22] => __toJSON [23] => __toString [24] => __toArray
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with `$sub_id`?

Comment: No, I did verify the sub_id that came back was valid in my stripe account. But I don't think it's actually making it that far, for some reason it just won't recognize the Subscription class... or at least that's what I think.

Comment: What does `print_r(get_class_methods('\Stripe\Subscription'))` do? Not sure it returns static methods though!

Comment: I updated with the results. Oddly it has results, and none of them are Retrieve...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve api is very new and requires the latest version of the stripe-php library (3.13.0), you should try updating your Stripe library.

Comment: Updated the library to 3.13.0 and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If don't wanna update stripe then simply use this function to `cancel` the `subscription`:

```
function cancelSubscription($stripeaccount){
      //$stripeaccount will be customer_id
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($stripeaccount);
    $sub_id->cancelSubscription(); 
      // cancelSubscription() is a function in Stripe_Customer Class,
      // So without getting subscription detail direct cancel the subscription 

 }
```

For more explanation, Please have a look here: [Can't cancel the subscription on stripe in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174904/cant-cancel-the-subscription-on-stripe-in-cakephp/)