# Can't cancel the subscription on stripe in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, stripe-payments

I'm using this Cakephp StripeComponent plugin : https://github.com/chronon/CakePHP-StripeComponent-Plugin

Everything is working fine but I can't cancel the subscription with this plugin.

I had tried this https://stripe.com/docs/api#cancel_subscription, but no success.

As its saying to `retrieve` the subscription and then `cancel()`But this plugin doesn't have any `retrieve subscription` function.

When I tried this,

```
$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve('SUBSCRIPTION_ID');
$sub->cancel();
```

I'm getting error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe\Subscription::retrieve()`

I'm stuck.. Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched this problem too much on google but I got only some results like

- Update Stripe library to 3.13.0.
- Add custom functions.... etc.

Finally I solved this problem by myself..

In the `StripeComponent.php`, write this function:

```
public function subscriptionCancel($cust_id) {
    Stripe::setApiKey($this->key);
    $customer = false;
    try {
        $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($cust_id);
        $customer->cancelSubscription();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return $customer;
}
```

And call this `function subscriptionCancel()` in your Controller as:

`$subscription = $this->Stripe->subscriptionCancel($cust_id);`

So the subscription related to particular `$cust_id` will be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function as

```
    Stripe_Subscription::retrieve('SUBSCRIPTION_ID')
```

Comment: I tried but got this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe\Subscription::retrieve()`