# Using Stripe PHP on localhost for development

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments

I am trying to setup Stripe on a localhost for development purposes on a Mac OS. All my PHP is installed and works perfectly. Localhost is ready and working. But I used `brew install composer` and then `composer require stripe/stripe-php`. Everything installed properly.

But I am getting the following error with my localhost pages:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe' not found in...
```

Do I need to require something inside my code? Or what is the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stripe - PHP Fatal error: Class 'Stripe\Charge' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846062/stripe-php-fatal-error-class-stripe-charge-not-found)

Comment: No, but I found the answer! I will add it below.

Comment: Please share more details, like: how does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. Inside your php, you need to add

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

If this does not work try:

```
require_once('/Users/USERNAME/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Change ***USERNAME*** to your localhost username.